# How to catch with RegExp first word with different first symbol in it using ed text editor

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression, ed

I have shell command:

```
printf '/^PermitRootLogin/\nc\nPermitRootLogin no\n.\nw\nq\n' | ed -s /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

And I need catch `#PermitRootLogin` like `PermitRootLogin` but not commented paragrath with this phrase in sentence, I'm using ed text editor and try to find some way to catch all occurrences with one RegExp in my command.

I don't have GNU utils on this OS.
Thank you for answer!

Comment: You need to provide what you actually tried, at the very least, and what the effect was. You can [edit] your post with more details.

Comment: I have few Unix servers, and I can to use 'ed' text editor to change all occurrences with `PermitRootLogin` in file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to `PermitRootLogin no`. In first server I have `PermitRootLogin` in second `#PermitRootLogin` and I need change them all with one command. I use: `printf '/^PermitRootLogin/\nc\nPermitRootLogin no\n.\nw\nq\n' | ed -s /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and it changes only `PermitRootLogin`, not `#PermitRootLogin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are not the same as shell glob patterns.  `^?` has no valid meaning as a regex because `^` matches beginning-of-line and `?` means 0 or 1 of the preceding sub-expression (in this case `^`).

Try this:

```
grep `^.?SomeString`
```

Explanation:

```
^           anchors the match to the start of the line
.?          means 0 or 1 of any character
SomeString  match "Somestring"
```

Comment: It does not work

Comment: i'd say that's got more to do with operator error than anything else, the regex IS correct for what you originally asked for.  Your question has changed beyond recognition from what it was when I answered it - and I gave you the answer to your question `Can't understand why /^?SomeString/g did not work for me. Thank you for answer!`.

Comment: I'd like to thank you, your solution work with egrep, not with grep.

Answer (score 0):

**a**, **i**, and **c** are stand-alone commands;
they must be followed by text *on the next line*. 
So, you need a newline after the **c**. 
You're already got the `\`; it looks like you just forgot to the the `n`.

```
printf '/^PermitRootLogin/\nc\nPermitRootLogin no\n.\nw\nq\n' | ed -s /etc/ssh/sshd_config
                              ↑
```

Comment: You are right, thank you, but I need some RegEx for catching two strings in ed.

Comment: Please edit your question to more clearly and completely explain what you want to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have few Unix servers, and I need to use 'ed' text editor to change all occurrences with`PermitRootLogin` in file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to `PermitRootLogin no`. In some files I have `PermitRootLogin` in other `#PermitRootLogin` and I need change them all.

Comment: I said clearly and completely.  You say that you want to catch `#PermitRootLogin` but not commented paragraphs containing `PermitRootLogin`.  What's the difference?  How is `ed` supposed to tell the difference between these cases?  P.S. I doubt that it will be possible to do this in a single RegExp in `ed` on a non-GNU system.  I can probably do it as a sequence of commands; do you want to see that?

Comment: Can you please. Something like `printf '/PermitRootLogin/d\nc\nPermitRootLogin no\n.\nw\nq\n' | ed -s /etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Pick an arbitrary string that will never appear in the config file. 
   It’s best to avoid special characters like `/`, `.`, `*`, `[` and `]`. 
   For example, I’ll use `<G-Man>`.
2. Do the following:

   ```
   ed -s /etc/ssh/sshd_config << EOF
           g/^#*PermitRootLogin/s/^/<G-Man>/
           g/^<G-Man>##*PermitRootLogin...../s/<G-Man>//
           1,$s/^<G-Man>\(#*PermitRootLogin\).*/\1 no/
           w
           q
   EOF
   ```
3. What does this do?

   It finds every line that

   - begins with `PermitRootLogin`, or
   - begins with one or more `#` characters,
     immediately followed by `PermitRootLogin` and at most four other characters,

   and changes it to `PermitRootLogin no`,
   leaving any `#` character(s) at the beginning of the line.
4. Huh?  What?  Why does it do that?

   The objective was to change any of the following lines:

   ```
   PermitRootLogin yes
   PermitRootLogin no
   PermitRootLogin The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
   #PermitRootLogin yes
   #PermitRootLogin no
   ```

   but not the following lines:

   ```
   #In this section we set
   #PermitRootLogin to “maybe”,
   #because we haven’t decided yet.
   ```

   It is a perhaps unfortunate side-effect of this design
   that the following lines:

   ```
   ##PermitRootLogin yes
   ##PermitRootLogin ???
   ```

   *will* be changed, and the following lines:

   ```
           PermitRootLogin yes
   # PermitRootLogin yes
           #PermitRootLogin yes
   ```

   will not.
5. How does it work?

   - `g/^#*PermitRootLogin/s/^/<G-Man>/`
     finds all lines that begin with `PermitRootLogin`,
     or begin with one or more `#` characters,
     immediately followed by `PermitRootLogin`,
     and “tags” them with the `<G-Man>` string
     (inserts it at the beginning of the line). 
     This will affect `PermitRootLogin` lines that are commented out,
     provided that there are no spaces (or anything else)
     before or after the `#` character(s).
   - `g/^<G-Man>##*PermitRootLogin...../s/<G-Man>//`
     finds all tagged lines that have *at least one* `#` at the beginning,
     and at least five characters after `PermitRootLogin`, and removes the tag. 
     This untags commented `PermitRootLogin` lines
     that have something that’s longer than  `yes`. 
     (Of course you can change the number of **`.`** characters if you want to.)
   - `1,$s/^<G-Man>\(#*PermitRootLogin\).*/\1 no/`
     finds all lines that are still tagged, removes the tag,
     captures the `PermitRootLogin` and all the preceding `#` character(s),
     keeps them, and replaces the rest of the line with  `no`.
6. Of course you can collapse those commands into a `printf` if you want to.